# Error while running liquibase script in GCP cloud environment

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

Using spring boot application with liquibase to create a DB tables and schema.
I am getting below error-
Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.7.0:update (default-cli) on project mlcrequest-db-schema: Error setting up or running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.SetupException: java.lang.NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.7.0:update (default-cli) on project mlcrequest-db-schema: Error setting up or running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.SetupException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)

I tried changing liquibase maven plugin version to 3.5.5 and usung JDK 11 in docker file.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I believe you are using maven for database installation. It should rather be done in your application.

Comment: This issue got fixed now as I used liquibase-maven-plugin version which is less that 3.5.5